# Read multiple comm port simultaneously using RxTx library in Java

Tags: java, rxtx

I have created an application to read data from multiple communication ports in Swing using RxTx library. Reading data from one communication port works fine but the other one shows port in use exception even I am trying to read from another port in the same window.

```
 public final void ReadData() {

    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[40];
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Main", 2000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error  " + e);
    }
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
    }
    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEventListener) this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too many listeners for data");

    }
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(baudrate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
    }
    readThread = new Thread((Runnable) this);
    readThread.start();
}
```

Comment: If port A works and B fails, what happens if you swap and open B first?  If now B works and A fails then the problem is in the RxTx code or something you're doing.  If B still fails and A opens successfully, then some other process owns B and isn't willing to let you have it. Investigate that.

Comment: @JimGarrison, If I swap both the ports get into the exception. Moreover, I don't know to listen to the individual ports in separate functions simultaneously.

Comment: You are going to need to research which process has port B open.  Use the `lsof` or `fuser` commands to find out.

Comment: Please post a simple but complete code that can be run and shall demonstrate the problem that you encountered. From the code above, the run method is not shown. One guess of mine is that you are opening the same port more than once while that port is not properly closed. This situation can cause "PortInUSeException".